# Using "using" statements for every object implementing IDisposable?

Tags: active-directory, idisposable, using-statement

I'm currently skimming through some code that reads Active Directory entries and manipulates them. Since I haven't had to do with this kind of stuff, I <kbd>F12</kbd>'d the classes (`DirectoryEntry`, `SearchResultCollection`, ...), and I found out they all implement the `IDisposable` interface, but I couldn't see any `using` blocks in our code.

Are those even necessary in this case (i.e., should I blindly refactor them in)?

Another question of mine regarding this (there are very many instantiated `IDisposable` objects in the code: Isn't `IDisposable` making stuff very "ugly" in this case? I mean, I like `using` statements as they basically free my mind from worrying about things, but in many cases the code has a layout similar to the following:

```
using (var one = myObject.GetSomeDisposableObject())
using (var two = myObject.GetSomeOtherDisposableObject())
{
  one.DoSomething();
  using (var foo = new DisposableFoo())
  {
    MyMethod(foo);
    using (...)
    using (...)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I feel that this becomes quite unreadable due to high indentation levels (even stacking the `using` statements). But extracting some of this into new methods can lead to many parameters that need to be passed, since naturally the "inner" code often needs the objects created in the `using` statements.

What is an elegant way to solve this without losing readability?

Comment: For the first part, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362341/dispose-not-working-as-expected-in-directorysearcher) refers to 'memory used by the task increasing constantly' when not disposing of AD references - for the second, a `using` block is syntactic sugar for a `try/finally` with the Dispose call in the `finally` block, which would be an alternative construct allowing you to dispose of everything in one place, reducing indentation.

Comment: @stuartd Thanks for the link, that sure looks interesting (I have to read it fully in a minute). As for `try/finally`, ouch! I forgot about that, of course I knew it existed but just didn't think further. Usually, with one or two `using` statements, it's not a preferred way, but with so many I could try using it. Too bad it doesn't automatically keep me from forgetting to `Dispose` of everything I declared above :D Feel free to add this as a short answer!

Comment: Added as answer, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362341/dispose-not-working-as-expected-in-directorysearcher) refers to 'memory used by the task increasing constantly' when not disposing of AD references

For the second, a `using` block is syntactic sugar for a `try/finally` with the `Dispose` call in the `finally` block, which would be an alternative construct allowing you to dispose of everything in one place, reducing indentation